# wait for Data on Serialport

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serial-port

I'm searching for a way to stop my progamm till my EventHandel have found enough data on serialport.

my code currently look like this Part01:

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
        RxHistorie.Add(RxString);
        textBox1.AppendText("\n");

    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

    }
```

Part02:

```
 private void createRandomPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int numRows, numCols,i,j;
            Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out numRows);
            Int32.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out numCols);
            j=RxHistorie.Count;

            string msg = String.Format("3,{0},{1},0", numRows, numCols);
            serialPort1.WriteLine(msg);
            bool done = false;
            while (!done)
            {

                if (RxHistorie.Count >= j + numCols * numRows)
                {done=true;}
            }
       }
```

have any one an idea ?

Comment: Don't use DataReceived if you want to stop the world.  Just call ReadLine() directly.  It will freeze your program until the port has received the string.  Do consider setting the ReadTimeout property so your program won't freeze forever when there's something wrong with the device.

Comment: ok i will try it on monday at work